# Android: Having trouble updating a row in a database after determining what row I need to update

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have a table that contains a list of devices with catagories like type, manufacturer and model and a device ID. Another table called system uses the device id to point to the table with the devices. I have a edit system function that I am trying to get working where I can edit the device id field in a record on the system table to change which device in the devices table I am pointing too. I run the update command and it looks like it should work but the row does not get updated. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my update code routine.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String UpdateDeviceName = txtEditDeviceName.getText().toString();
String UpdateDeviceIP = txtEditDeviceIP.getText().toString();
//get the new device id based off of the three spinner values
String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dbHelper.Devices_Table + ";";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(dbQuery, null);
if (c.getCount() > 0)
{
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        int iColumnID = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID);
        int iColumnDeviceType = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Type);
        int iColumnDeviceManufacturer = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Manufacturer);
        int iColumnDeviceModel = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Model);
        String CheckDeviceType = c.getString(iColumnDeviceType);
        if (CheckDeviceType.equals(DeviceType))
        {
            String CheckDeviceManufacturer = c.getString(iColumnDeviceManufacturer);
            if (CheckDeviceManufacturer.equals(DeviceManufacturer))
            {
                String CheckDeviceModel = c.getString(iColumnDeviceModel);
                if (CheckDeviceModel.equals(DeviceModel))
                {
                    DeviceID = c.getString(iColumnID);
                }
             }
         }
      }
}
db.close();
c.close();
db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//with the device ID update the system
dbQuery = "UPDATE " + dbHelper.System_Table + " SET " + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID + " = " + DeviceID + ", " +
    dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Name + " = '" + UpdateDeviceName + "', " +
    dbHelper.Attribute_Device_IP + " = '" +
    UpdateDeviceIP + "' WHERE " + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID + " = " + OrginalDeviceID + ";";
c = db.rawQuery(dbQuery, null);
Log.d("Database Dump", "Edit Device Query: " + dbQuery);
c.close();
db.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. FIrst off I want to thank Henry and Wolfram Rittmeyer. You guys where very helpful. :)

For whatever reason the android SQLite does not like to use the update statement in raw sql query form. In researching what Wolfram Rittmeyer said about updateWithConflict I found the update method in the SQLiteOpenHelper object which my dbHelper extends. When I switched to that method I was able to update the database. My where conditions have been expanded on to include the device name as well in the event that the system has more then one device make and model of the same type and only one has to change.

For reference the working code to update the database is the following. I'm only posting the changed portion of the code. Everything in the if (c.getCount() > 0) block and above is unchanged.

```
c.close();
dbHelper.close();
db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//with the device ID update the system
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID, DeviceID);
values.put(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Name, UpdateDeviceName);
values.put(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_IP, UpdateDeviceIP);
String Where = dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID + " = " + OrginalDeviceID +  " AND " + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Name + " = '" + OrginalDeviceName + "'";
db.update(dbHelper.System_Table, values, Where, null);
c.close();
dbHelper.close();
finish(); //this exits the activity and goes back to the calling activity
```

Comment: If you think Henry's and my answer were helpful, you should upvote them. That's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I can't right now because it says I need 15 reputation points but I will as soon as I have the points. :)

Answer (score 1):

You closed the DB after the search:

```
db.close();
```

leave out this line, since the DB helper code prefers to keep the DB open until it is no longer used (use `dbHelper.close()` to close the DB when you are done with it).

The same applies after the update.

Comment: I removed the db.close(); from the routine but it still isn't updating.

Comment: No I don't. I have the logCat section set to verbose too.

Also here is what the update statement is parsing out to. It looks correct.

dbQuery "UPDATE System SET Device_ID = 6, Device_Name = 'Test Receiver', Device_IP = '192.168.1.125' WHERE Device_ID = 7;"

Comment: @user1952364: u can try as `dbQuery = "UPDATE " + dbHelper.System_Table + " SET " + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID + " = " + DeviceID + ", " +
    dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Name + " =" + UpdateDeviceName + ", " +
    dbHelper.Attribute_Device_IP + " = " +
    UpdateDeviceIP + " WHERE " + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID + " = " + OrginalDeviceID + ";";`

Comment: Is Device_ID the primary key in the table? Are there any foreign keys referencing it?

Comment: Yes it is on the Devices table. On the System table the DeviceID is used to point it to the row in the the Devices table for the information it needs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all any `rawQuery` statement must not contain the trailing semicolon! See the documentation of [`SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29).

Also you always must close cursors before closing the database. And you *have* to close the db when you get a new one for each query. Otherwise the system at some point later on will throw exceptions. While those only will be logged and do not cause a Force Close, you should still care about proper resource management.

Finally you should use the [`updateWithOnConflict`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#updateWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%29) method instead with using [`CONFLICT_REPLACE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_REPLACE) as the conflictAlgorithm. This simply ignores any `UNIQUE` constraints and overwrites conflicting rows. So be careful. If you do not want to overwrite existing rows you have to make sure that a constarint violation isn't causing your problem.

Comment: I tried having the close cursor and then close db. However it is still not updating the row. I am at a loss. I don't understand why the command is not executing.

Comment: That was just one of three points. Did you follow those others (trailing ";" and `updateWithOnConflict`)? Could you explain the data structure? And please post a logcat excerpt (even if you think there is nothing to see) including a log statement of the number of updates rows returned by the `updateWithOnConflict` method.